# Implementing Oauth within a Chrome extension

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, twitter, oauth

I'm looking to implement OAuth through Google, Twitter, Yahoo and Facebook.

I've seen the Chrome tutorial (http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/) as well as Boris Smus's library (http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/), but they don't seem very extensive and each provider has implemented oauth differently. Does anyone know of a better/easier way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome introduced the Identity API for OAuth, available in Chrome 29 and later:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity